# Add trigger event to input when clicked on containing div

Tags: jquery, forms, triggers, submit, form-submit

What I have is a address field and to the right of the address field is a arrow (>) acting as an input button. Right now only the arrow is clickable and I need it so when a user clicks on the entire field (this is for mobile) - the click is triggered on the input field to move forward. It simply takes the user to another page to choose a different address or add another address.

```
<div id="addrChng">
    <form action="actName" method="post">
        <input id="addrSubmit" type="submit" name="actName" />
    </form>
    <p>
     --first name
     --last name
     --street name
    </p>
</div>
```

The snippet I've tried to use is this:

```
$('#addrChng').click(function() {
    $('#addrSubmit').trigger('click');
});
```

I've tried things like using .find() to get the input field. I've tried .on('click', 'input' function() etc etc. So far nothing seems to work. So clicking the input itself works, but trying to trigger the input by clicking the entire div does not.

Comment: Your code should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kph63s72/. You should stop propagation of the event though so it doesn't cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the form:

```
<form id="formId" action="actName" method="post">
...
```

And then...

```
$('#addrChng').click(function() {
    $('#formId').submit();
});
```

Comment: Tried that. Submit doesn't move forward. I added an alert to make sure its recognizing my click and it is. The input field won't move the page forward though.

Comment: You have to add an id to the form for that to work, or select it another way.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.  Edited my answer for clarity.